# How to check sending email address before sending?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I use multiple accounts in Outlook. I want to give a warning box if sending from an address I should not be sending from.

I have two addresses that I should never send from (they are receive only accounts).

This example is almost what I am looking for.
[Example - Checking the "To" address.](http://www.slipstick.com/how-to-outlook/prevent-sending-messages-to-wrong-email-address/)

I believe a string comparison (StrComp) and `Item.SenderEmailAddress` is what I need.

Here is my attempt for giving a warning for a single email address (bad.email@gmail.com).

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
            
On Error Resume Next
' use lower case for the address
' LCase converts all addresses in the To field to lower case
If StrComp((Item.SenderEmailAddress), "bad.email@gmail.com") Then
    Exit Sub
End If
    
Prompt$ = "You sending this from " & Item.SenderEmailAddress & ". Are you sure you want to send it?"
If MsgBox(Prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
    Cancel = True
End If

End Sub
```

Ideally I would to check two or more addresses with the same code. Something like in the example should work.

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
On Error Resume Next
Select Case LCase(Item.To)
Case "alias@domain.com", "alias2@domain3.com", "alias3@domain3.com"
    Item.Send
Case Else
    Prompt$ = "You are not sending this to " & Item.To & ". Are you sure you want to send the Mail?"
    If MsgBox(Prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
    
End Select
    
End Sub
```

Also, where do I place the code to ensure that it is constantly running and ready?

Comment: SenderEmailAddress "Returns a String that represents the e-mail address of the sender of the Outlook item. Read-only." Does not exists on unsent mail.

Comment: Are you checking the sender address or the recipient address?

Comment: Checking the sender (from) address

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SendUsingAccount` - as noted, `SenderEmailAddress` doesn't exist on unsent mail.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim sendAddress As String
    Dim prompt As String

    ' Check Send_from name
    sendAddress = Item.SendUsingAccount.SmtpAddress

    Select Case sendAddress
        Case "alias@domain.com", "alias2@domain3.com", "alias3@domain3.com"
            ' send
        Case Else
            prompt = "You are currently sending this email from " & sendAddress & ". Are you sure you want to proceed?"
            If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground + vbDefaultButton2, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
            End If        
    End Select

End Sub
```

You should paste this code in `ThisOutlookSession`, under Microsoft Outlook Objects in the VBA Editor.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will give this a try.

Comment: It seems to be giving the warning no matter which account I send from.

Comment: Is it checking the actual email address, or just the display name? Because the display name may be the same for each account.

Comment: Edited - try SmtpAddress instead of DisplayName.

Comment: That doesn't work either. It just sends the emails as normal with no warning.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't realize I had to put in the addresses that are Good to send from. I had the prohibited addresses in before. 

The problem now is with both SmtpAddress and DisplayName gives a warning on each address. 

For example ben.company@gmail.com and ben@company.com both gives warnings when only ben.company@gmail.com should give a warning. Each account has the same display name.

Comment: Use Debug.Print Send_Address to compare the Item's send address to the addresses you have typed it in your Case statement - possibly a typo?

Comment: Complains about the "Item.Send" for me but commenting that out and relying only on the Cancel variable appears to work fine. Would also recommend adding "+ vbDefaultButton2" so that the "No" is the default button.

Answer (score 1):

*I  think it should be [MailItem.SendUsingAccount Property (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-sendusingaccount-property-outlook)*

> <sub>Which returns or sets an [Account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/account-object-outlook) object that represents the account under which the [MailItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-object-outlook) is to be sent. Read/write, also see [MailItem.SendUsingAccount Property.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb207787(v=office.12).aspx)</sub>

*Example*

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Prompt As String
        Prompt = "Are you sure you want to send from 0m3r@Email.com?"

        If Item.SendUsingAccount = "0m3r@Email.com" Then
            If MsgBox(Prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
            End If
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me either, I get no prompts.